# Ubuntu Core - Network Tools

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

I need to know which network tool i can use to grasp network informations, such as interface configured, open ports, TCP/UDP traffic in Ubuntu Core! I can't use netstat, ifconfig, lsof and so on .... So which tools can i use ??

I'm talking about Ubuntu Core 18, in this environment these tools don't exists!!

Comment: "I can't use netstat, ifconfig and so on .... So which tools can i use ?" -  why not? Those are the tools for the tasks you list. Is this homework?

Comment: When you say "I can't use", do you mean you're not permitted to use those tools or that those tools don't exist on your environment?

Comment: For the moment the only network/socket tool i've found is  ss

Comment: Have you tried *installing* some of these tools?  `ifconfig` is no longer included by default anymore, in favor of `ip` commands to get information about currently configured IP stuff, `ss` is equally usable to lsof if you look up the specifics of how to use it (https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-investigate-sockets-network-connections.html).  Most of the tools you've stated are 'extra utilities', `ip` is part of the system as is `ss` by default typically.

Answer (score 0):

The toolbox snap (https://snapcraft.io/toolbox) ships some of these tools.

I think netstat is missing, but if you contact ondra through the contact link on the above website he will surely add it quickly to the snap ...